# New Inertia Route in laravel returns 404

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, inertiajs

I am trying to register a new route in Intertia for Laravel, but everything except the first route gives me an 404. These are my routes in web.php:

```
Route::get('/app', function () { return Inertia::render('Atlas/App'); });
Route::get('/test', function () { return Inertia::render('Test/Test'); });
Route::get('/test2', function () { return Inertia::render('Test/Test2'); });

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

and these are my files:

App.vue:

```
<template>
<div>
    Test
</div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    name: "App",

    props: ['sessions'],
}
</script>
```

and Test.vue:

```
<template>
<div>
    Test
</div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
    name: "Test",

    props: ['sessions'],
}
</script>
```

Below you can see my file structure:

[image: Structure]

I have tried running php artisan serve and npm run watch several times, no changes. Am I missing something important? The only route that is working is /test, which is basically identical to /test2 and /app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inertia Route helpers](https://inertiajs.com/routing) like this :

```
Route::inertia('/app', 'Atlas/App');
Route::inertia('/test', 'Test/Test');
Route::inertia('/test2', 'Test/Test2');
```